# How to unit test return value of function - Angular (Jasmine/Karma)

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I am wondering if there is a way to correctly test the return value of a function in Angular. I want to essentially test the return value to be true for one test and write another to test the opposite scenario.

Ts component:

```
    get() {
        if (this.object == undefined) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }    
    }
```

The only way I can see fit right now to test the return value is to set a variable to hold the return value. Below is my attempt, I'm just stuck on asserting what is to be expected.

Test:

```
it('should call get function and return true', () => {
        //Arrange
        component.object = undefined;

        //Act
        component.get();

        //Assert
        expect(component.get). <-- *stuck here*

    });
```

Comment: A great tips and techniques resource for unit testing Angular: https://angular.io/guide/testing

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Get the value in the *act* and then check it to be `true` in the *assert*.

```
it('should call get function and return true', () => {
        // Arrange
        component.object = undefined;

        // Act
        var result = component.get();

        // Assert
        expect(result).toBe(true);
    });
```

---

On a side note the body of the method `get` could be simplified to just

```
return this.object === undefined;
```

Comment: ```expect(result).toBeTruthy();``` // it should be toBeTruthy()

Comment: @Manoj should be `expect(result).toBeTrue();`