# How to test the returned value of a method [Jasmine]

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine

I'm new in unit testing using Jasmine and Karma. My question is very much similar to this:

[How to unit test return value of function - Angular (Jasmine/Karma)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55230057/how-to-unit-test-return-value-of-function-angular-jasmine-karma)

But mine is different as I want to check the length of the returned value instead of the value itself. I've a method which takes `n` as a number. If the number is below 10 then the method should return the same number but with a preceding **0** as string. Valid range is **0 to 12** (actually it is a part of month picker component. I'm trying to achieve `MM` format.). For e.g if **5** is input then the returned value should be **05** as string. Here's the code:

```
convertToDoubleDigit(n) {
    n = String(n);
    if (n.length === 1) {
        n = '0' + n;
    }
    return n;
}
```

and my test case is:

```
it('should call convertToDoubleDigit and convert to double digit', () => {
    fixture.componentInstance.convertToDoubleDigit(2);
    expect(fixture.componentInstance.length) <----- This is what I'm asking
})
```

I know that I should do something like:

`expect(fixture.componentInstance......length).toBe(2)`

Please help me test this part. I'm unable to think out of the box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not be checking for the length, but `instead of value here would valid test case`:

```
it('should call convertToDoubleDigit and convert to double digit', () => {
    fixture.componentInstance.convertToDoubleDigit(2);
    expect(fixture.componentInstance.value).toEqual(02)
})
```

Comment: ohhhh...Thank you so much Rajnikanth Sir. (I'm your huge fan already). So i think `length` should be used when checking an array is populated or not. Correct me If I'm wrong.

Comment: But `value` would be undefined. Whose value we are checking here? Because `n` is a parameter that was local to `convertToDoubleDigit` method only.

Comment: @Tanzeel: in that case you should use spyOn on that function.

Comment: Yes I also thought so. I'm trying that only. I'll get back to you. Give me 5 mins please.

Comment: Shouldn't I do something like:
`expect(fixture.componentInstance.convertToDoubleDigit(2)).toBe("02");`

Comment: if converToDoubleDigit is not a private function, then you should be able to do that.

Comment: Yes, It is not a private method, it is public. But that way I'm not following Arrange-Act-Assert pattern of testing. My tech lead will not be very happy. What do you think ? Is it a good practice ?

Comment: general rule of thumb is not to test private methods, you can't and only test public methods. Some can be covered in unit testing and some in E2E... code coverage can at max be around 80%